# Tableau Desktop Move column header to bottom

Tags: tableau-api

I've a report that shows Years, Production in tonnes and Countries. I'm trying to move the column header that is 'Years' to the bottom of the report. Here is the image.

[image: Tableu desktop report]

Comment: try swapping fields in column shelf... country first and then year after that

Answer (score 1):

Tableau differentiates headers from axis. Headers are always at the top and headers are provided for discrete values (blue pill). Axis, on the other hand, default to the bottom unless you have a dual-axis chart, and an axis is only for continuous values (green pill).

From your screenshot, Year is a discrete value, hence it can only display the header at the top. You can try switching Year to be a continuous value so that an axis will show at the bottom.